# Conformal mapping of the unit circle minus a smaller circle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> Map the region inside the circle $|z| = 1$ and outside the circle
>   $|z-1/2| = 1/2$ conformally onto the unit disk.

I was thinking of using some scaling and shifting to get from the unit circle to the circle $|z-1/2| = 1/2$. but I'm not sure how that might be useful since it doesn't help with getting the region we want. The other idea I had was to work backwards starting with the unit circle to get to the region we want.

Source: [Spring 1992](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Pre_2012_papers/complex_analysis_Pre_2011.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What happens to that region under the map $z\to (1+z)/(1-z)?$

Comment: I think this mapping takes the unit circle to the right half plane? but I'm not sure how it affects the inner circle.

Comment: Yes on the right half plane. As for the other circle, a linear fractional transformation takes a circle through a pole to what?

Comment: oh I see, it becomes a vertical line through x=1. Is there a nice way to show that though? I just used trig, but I feel like I'm missing some complex analysis technique.  So now we're left with the right half plane minus the strip from 0 to 1 right?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ goes to $\mathbb R.$ Big circle therefore goes to a line $\perp$ to $\mathbb R$ and so does the small circle. $-1$ is on the big circle and goes to $0$, $0$ is on small circle and goes to $1$ Our region therefore goes to $\{x+iy: 0<x<1\}.$

Comment: ah yes, I inverted it.  So to finish it off, you would multiply it by $i$ to rotate it, then use $z \to e^z$ get from the horizontal strip to the unit disk?

Answer (score 0):

To finish it off, @¡YOA, after the transformation $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ suggested by @zhw. there are two more steps to take. The first one maps the vertical stripe onto $\{z: \Im z \geq0\}$ by means of $e^{i\pi z}$. 
(Note that $|e^{i\pi z}|= |e^{i\pi (x+iy)}|=|e^{-\pi y}| \in (-\infty, \infty)$
. And Arg$(e^{i \pi z}) = \pi x \in [0,\pi]$, as $x \in[0,1]$.)

The last transformation maps the upper half plane onto the unit disc using a usual Möbius mapping.